# how to know the exact reason why FileWriter file = new FileWriter('...', append); failed?

Tags: java, android, filewriter

when `FileWriter file = new FileWriter(' /data/data/com.myapp.app/files/locationservices.json', true/*append*/);` return me the error :

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /data/data/com.myapp.app/files/locationservices.json (No such file
>   or directory)

how to know exactly why it's failed to create the file?

Comment: Most probably, it's because some directories in the path do not exist.

Comment: no it's seam the directory exist

Comment: I suppose the exception message is pretty much what you need. You expect the constructor to create a file, instead it throws a "no such file or directory". The logical conclusion is that the file can't be created. If it was for a permission problem, it would have thrown a java.io.FilePermission, so it can't be created because there is no directory to create it in.

Comment: either permission or directory error problem as @Tu.ma said, but in addition this also happens if the file has special characters in its name such as : , . space etc. results in Permission denied error even though you do have the proper permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
File file = new File(uri);
file.mkdirs()
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file , true)
```

Comment: 1) What if `mkdirs()` fails?  You are not testing the result.  2) Since Java 7, it is better to use `java.nio.file.Files::createDirectories`.